# init data from API using async function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm learning Ionic/Angular for my first app. I have to load datas from an API on init and display them in my view.

In my code, I'm calling the async function which contains the API call on `ngOnInit()`. I would like to initialize datas from a specific param.

The problem is: when `ngOnInit()` is called, the async function is not yet finished, so my vars in view are `null`.

**How could I do that?**

Here is the code :

```
async getData(id) {
    try {
      const url = 'http://url/api/pages/'+id;
      const params = {};
      const headers = {};
      const response = await this.http.get(url, params, headers);

      console.log(JSON.parse(response.data)); 
      this.page = JSON.parse(response.data);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.status);
      console.error(error.error); 
      console.error(error.headers);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData(11);
  }
```

And the view with var page :

```
<p>{{ page.text }}</p>
```

Comment: Try `<p>{{ page?.text }}</p>`. This way you will check if the `page` has `text` property.

Comment: Ok, so I won't have errors for null values. And how to fill the vars when the API after the API is called as the view will be already displayed? Thank you

Comment: The problem I see here is that you're using `await` and `http.get` returns an `observable`. You will need to checkout rxjs, or how to `subscribe` to these observables, because even if you await them they are still not resolved. They work in a different way. I bet `console.log(JSON.parse(response.data));` this line gives you an error of some sort.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov I think you're right. It should be either: `const response = await this.http.get(url, params, headers).toPromise();` or `this.http.get(url, params, headers).subscribe((response) => this.page = response.data);`

Comment: Can I subscribe directly to http response as your second suggestion ?

Comment: @TyYt, yes you can. See my answer updated. Hope it helps you better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding to the data retrieval, you can either:

- keep the *async/await* pair converting the result of `this.http.get` to a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) like this: `const response = await this.http.get(url, params, headers).toPromise();`
- or do not use the *async/await* pair and subscribe the the [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables) returned by `http.get`, like this: `this.http.get(url, params, headers).subscribe((response) => this.page = response.data);`

So, it would be either:

```
async getData(id) {
    // ...
      const response = await this.http.get(url, params, headers).toPromise();
      this.page = JSON.parse(response.data);
    // ...
}
```

or ...

```
getData(id) {
    // ...
      this.http.get(url, params, headers).subscribe((response) => {
           this.page = response.data
      });
    // ...
}
```

---

Regarding to the view rendering:

Option 1: [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) in any of its flavours.

i.e.: If you want to show a temporary text indicating that the value is loading:

```
<p *ngIf="!!page; else elseBlock">{{ page.text }}</p>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Loading data...</ng-template>
```

Option 2: [The safe navigation operator ( ? )](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator). If it's acceptable to show a blank value while loading the `page` you could do it like this:

```
<p>{{ page?.text }}</p>
```

In both cases, after the `page` gets the values from the API, the HTML view will be updated by the framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that. Now I'm facing some CORS issues, will check that too. Thanks

Comment: @TyYt CORS is a whole different story. You didn't face it before because the request was not actually being performed. After this changes the API is now being called. Hope you solve it :) if this was useful, please consider [up-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it.